# How to convert time of 00:00 (HH:MM) to 24:00 in pandas (python) date column?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a csv file with datetime column. I use `pandas.read_csv(file, index_col="Date", parse_date=True)` to read the csv. The datetime columns has 30min freq/res, so the first time of a given date is `00:30:00`, but the last time is not what I want:

[image]

As you can see, time 00:00:00 of a given date (here `2015-12-01`) is interpreted as next day.
I couldn't find a way to resolve this. In this example, I want:
`2015-12-02 00:00:00` be interpreted as `205-12-01 24:00:00` or something that refers to the correct date.

Does anyone know how to do in in pandas?

Edit:
So what I want is when I get the date for this time 00:00:00, it give me date of yesterday (so it sees the time as 23:59:59):
I want this:

```
2015-12-01 23:00:00    Tuesday  2015-12-01
2015-12-01 23:30:00    Tuesday  2015-12-01
2015-12-02 00:00:00  Wednesday  2015-12-02
2015-12-02 00:30:00  Wednesday  2015-12-02
```

be this:

```
2015-12-01 23:00:00    Tuesday  2015-12-01
2015-12-01 23:30:00    Tuesday  2015-12-01
2015-12-01 23:59:59    Tuesday  2015-12-01
2015-12-02 00:30:00  Wednesday  2015-12-02
```

be this

Comment: This is the default pandas format tho...

Comment: yeah, but that's wrong for what I'm doing

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Do you want text or datetime objects? How is it wrong for what you want to do (what do you want to do?)

Comment: What you require doesn't make sense. Should 00:30 in the morning be interpreted as 24 hours and 30 minutes of the previous day? No, exactly. It simply makes sense for the day to start from midnight.

Comment: I optimistically tried to create a `datetime` object with `hour=24` but you get an error. Adding a `timedelta(hours=24)` obviously wraps to the next day.

Comment: I think I explained what I want. I want 00:00:00 be interpreted as the last time of yesterday. for example when I extract the date form datetime column, the date return for 00:00:00 is yesterday.

Comment: @mas you have not answered either of my questions. Are strings fine? Why do you need this?

Comment: @mozway you str is fine

Comment: And the second question?...

Comment: @mozway I have other values (e.g prices) for each datetime and for these 00:00:00 , which for some finance reasons these values are required to be considered for the day before; however they data we get is what I showed. So I want a nice and fast way to do this change.

Comment: @mas Check my answer below

Comment: @mas I provided you with a [working answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68993174/16343464). Alternatively, if you only need the day for a group operation, you could keep a datetime object only with the previous day when time is '00:00:00'

Comment: I also provided an answer to your updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually quite simple if you can use strings. If the time is '00:00:00', subtract one day, convert to string, replace '00:00:00' with '24:00:00'.

```
import datetime
s = pd.Series(['2015-12-01 23:00:00', '2015-12-01 00:00:00'])
s = pd.to_datetime(s)
s.where(s.dt.time != datetime.time(0),
        ((s-pd.to_timedelta('1day'))
         .dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
         .str.replace('00:00:00', '24:00:00')
        )
       )
```

Output:

```
0    2015-12-01 23:00:00
1    2015-11-30 24:00:00
```

Or, for your edit:

```
df['col1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col1'])
df['col1'] = df['col1'].where(df['col1'].dt.time != datetime.time(0),
                              (df['col1']-pd.to_timedelta('1s'))
                             )
df['col2'] = df['col1'].dt.day_name()
df['col3'] = df['col1'].dt.date
```

output:

```
                 col1       col2        col3
0 2015-12-01 23:00:00    Tuesday  2015-12-01
1 2015-12-01 23:30:00    Tuesday  2015-12-01
2 2015-12-01 23:59:59    Tuesday  2015-12-01
3 2015-12-02 00:30:00  Wednesday  2015-12-02
```

Answer (score 1):

(A bit late but) You can use `dt.normalize` to find values to modify and subtract one second then change other columns according to DateTime column.

Input data:

```
>>> df
             DateTime  DayOfWeek       Date
0 2015-12-01 23:00:00    Tuesday 2015-12-01
1 2015-12-01 23:30:00    Tuesday 2015-12-01
2 2015-12-02 00:00:00  Wednesday 2015-12-02
3 2015-12-02 00:30:00  Wednesday 2015-12-02

>>> df.dtypes
DateTime     datetime64[ns]
DayOfWeek            object
Date         datetime64[ns]
```

```
new = df.loc[df['DateTime'].eq(df['DateTime'].dt.normalize()), ['DateTime']] \
        .sub(pd.DateOffset(seconds=1))

new = new.assign(DayOfWeek=new['DateTime'].dt.day_name(), 
                 Date=new['DateTime'].dt.normalize())

df.update(new)
```

Output result:

```
>>> df
             DateTime  DayOfWeek       Date
0 2015-12-01 23:00:00    Tuesday 2015-12-01
1 2015-12-01 23:30:00    Tuesday 2015-12-01
2 2015-12-01 23:59:59    Tuesday 2015-12-01
3 2015-12-02 00:30:00  Wednesday 2015-12-02
4 2021-08-30 23:59:59     Monday 2021-08-30
```